# Char in DVI file coded as 0x03 while actual hex value is 0xA4

Tags: tex-core, dvi

latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
$\mathbf{p}^*$
\end{document}
```

output of dviasm on DVI of this file:

```
[preamble]
id: 2
numerator: 25400000
denominator: 473628672
magnification: 1000
comment: ' TeX output 2018.04.12:1533'

[postamble]
maxv: 632.500000pt
maxh: 429pt
maxs: 4
pages: 1

[font definitions]
fntdef: cmsy8 at 8pt
fntdef: cmbx12 at 12pt

[page 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
down: 632.500000pt
push:
  down: -603.500000pt
  down: 573.500000pt
  push:
    down: -536.500000pt
    push:
      right: 56.624817pt
      fnt: cmbx12 at 12pt
      set: 'p'
      push:
        down: -4.354706pt
        fnt: cmsy8 at 8pt
        set: '\x03'
      pop:
    pop:
  pop:
pop:
```

Why is the asterisk coded by 0x03 when its actual number in the font table of cmsy8 is 164 (0xA4)?

This is not a bug in dviasm. I checked the actual .dvi file. The *set_char_3* optcode is there. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no glyph in `cmsy8` in slots beyond `"7F`. The (centered) asterisk is at position `"03`. What makes you think it's at `"A4`?

Comment: @egreg: Fontforge. But I was working with cmsy8.ttf. The PFB font has it on slot 0x03 as you say.

Comment: Curious decision by the author of `cmsy8.ttf` of placing the asterisk in the slot Unicode reserves to CURRENCY SIGN.

Comment: Such TTFs come e.g. with lyx or matplotlib (for those, cmsy8.ttf is not present in the distribution but cmsy10.ttf is, with the same position of asterisk at 0xA4). However, fontforge correctly names the symbol as "asteriskmath" although it also tells us its UTF8 ('CURRENCY SIGN') So, I must be missing a mapping table.

Answer (score 3):

This is the table of the `cmsy8` font

[image]

You can generate it yourself by running an interactive session doing

```
pdflatex nfssfont
```

answering `cmsy8<return>` at the first prompt and `\table\bye<return>` at the next.

As you see the asterisk is at slot `0x03` and there is no glyph beyond slot `0x7F`.

The mathcode of the asterisk is indeed `"2203` (binary operation in math family 2 at slot `"03`).